# Linking Microsoft Lists Calendar To Specific Month

Tags: list, calendar, microsoft

In SharePoint calendars it is possible to link/display a calendar to a specific month using the URL addition seen below:
`x?CalendarDate=10/01/2023&CalendarPeriod=month`

The above will open the calendar and display on the October month.

I am yet to find a way to achieve this through the Microsoft Lists Calendar View, is this at all possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible while using [SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists modern calendar view](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/).